# Is there a container that can handle touch events in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Xamarin Forms and I want to add three labels with three different colours inside a container so when the container is pressed it invokes an event handler.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pinch/ - here is good tutorial on it. It allows to create container that recognize any gesture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this you can use the `Gestures`.
There are a couple of default recognizers available in Xamarin.Forms, including the `TapGestureRecognizer`.

You can add them to virtually any visual element. Have a look at a simple implementation which binds to an `Image`.

```
var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) => {
    // handle the tap
};
image.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

Or in XAML:

```
<Image Source="tapped.jpg">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
                Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

As you can see you can also set the `NumberOfTapsRequired` to enable it for more taps before it takes action.
You can use `Commands` instead as well.

Other gestures are [Pinch](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pinch/) and [Pan](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/pan/) and the documentation on Tap can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/gestures/tap/).

In a example for what you are asking specifically try something like this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="handle" />
    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

    <Label x:Name="myLabel" Text="Open Search" FontSize="30" TextColor="Blue" />
    <Label x:Name="myLabel2" Text="URL" FontSize="30" TextColor="Green" /> 
</StackLayout>
```

This handles the gesture for the whole group.
If you want it per `Label`, do this:

```
<Label x:Name="myLabel2" Text="URL" FontSize="30" TextColor="Green">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="handle" />
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Comment: can you please show me how to use `<TapGestureRecognizer>` for adding a group of labels with different colors when I try this:
`<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="handle">
    <Label x:Name="myLabel" Text="Open Search" FontSize="30" TextColor="Blue" />
    <Label x:Name="myLabel2" Text="URL" FontSize="30" TextColor="Green" />
  </TapGestureRecognizer>`
I get an error